# RAM memory volatility

Tags: microcontroller, ram, volatile

We have an ECU with 8KB of RAM memory which has been divided into segments in the `.xcl` file (NO_INIT, ECU_ID,INIT etc). In our code, depending on `#pragmas`, we have the variable going into their respective segments. Now is my assumption true that irrespective of where the variables go, they are always cleared on power ON reset?

There is a `crt.asm` file which has the startup code. Is there a possibility of defining in this file what area of RAM needs to be cleared and what shouldn't, when the micro is reset?

Comment: If code does not specifically clear RAM there is no guarantee that it will be clear after power up.  In other words, if the NO_INIT segment tells your compiler/linker to leave this memory untouched, you cannot expect it to be clear.  Still, however, memory that is meant to be initialized must be done so by some code, if not yours, the compiler's startup code.

Comment: You should never read memory before you have written it.  In general ram comes up random.  Normally software you or the bootstrap, initialize it to zeros or other before use.  Some specialized hardware might do that for certain use cases, but not normally in the design.

Comment: DRAM initialization routines may exercise the interface on boot in order to train/tune, but that doesnt mean all of the memory will be initialized.  Nor does that mean zeros.